# Regex DNS ANSWER SECTION into groups

Tags: regex, dns, unbound

I've been trying for a while to regex the fields from the ANSWERS SECTION in the unbound logs.

This regex only extracts the last entry in the ANSWERS section:

```
(?:ANSWER\sSECTION:\s(?:(?<answer_name>\S+)#011(?<answer_ttl>\S+)#011(?<answer_class>\S+)#011(?<answer_type>\S+)#011(?<answer_rdata>\S+)\s)+\s\;\;)
```

This entry extracts everything in the ANSWERS SECTION, but also leaks into the AUTHORITY SECTION

```
(?:(?<answer_name>\S+)#011(?<answer_ttl>\S+)#011(?<answer_class>\S+)#011(?<answer_type>\S+)#011(?<answer_rdata>\S+)\s)
```

my goal is to have each of the answers in a group. Any thoughts on how to limit the groups to the ANSWERS SECTION while still capturing repeating groups?

logs:

```
 2019-01-02T17:34:19-05:00 10.10.30.1 unbound: [48511:0] info: incoming scrubbed packet: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0 ;; flags: qr rd ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0  ;; QUESTION SECTION: gs-loc.ls-apple.com.akadns.net.#011IN#011A  ;; ANSWER SECTION: gs-loc.ls-apple.com.akadns.net.#01135#011IN#011A#01117.142.171.4 gs-loc.ls-apple.com.akadns.net.#01135#011IN#011A#01117.142.171.8 gs-loc.ls-apple.com.akadns.net.#01135#011IN#011A#01117.142.171.9  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:  ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96

 2019-01-02T17:34:42-05:00 10.10.30.1 unbound: [48511:0] info: cname msg ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0 ;; flags: qr rd ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0  ;; QUESTION SECTION: init-p01md.apple.com.#011IN#011A  ;; ANSWER SECTION: init-p01md.apple.com.#0119665#011IN#011CNAME#011init-p01md-lb.push-apple.com.akadns.net.  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:  ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 91

 2019-01-02T18:52:01-05:00 10.10.30.1 unbound: [48511:0] info: msg from cache lookup ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0 ;; flags: qr rd ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 6, ADDITIONAL: 0  ;; QUESTION SECTION: amazonaws.com.#011IN#011DS  ;; ANSWER SECTION:  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.#01181254#011IN#011NSEC3#0111 1 0 - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM ;{flags: optout} xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com.#01181254#011IN#011RRSIG#011NSEC3 8 2 86400 20190107054258 20181231043258 37490 com. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx= ;{id = 37490} com.#011884#011IN#011SOA#011a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1546473084 1800 900 604800 86400 com.#011884#011IN#011RRSIG#011SOA 8 1 900 20190109235124 20190102224124 37490 com. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/bJiZwA/1

Comment: Thank you! that is prefect!

Comment: `This regex only extracts the last entry in the ANSWERS section:` What do you mean by this ? The regex matches 2 entries in the log. Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: within the ANSWER SECTION, there can be multiple answers to the dns question. i want to extract each answer into groups, and more specifically, each portion of each answer into specific groups. the regex that solved it does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)\s*|ANSWER\sSECTION:)\s*(?<answer_name>\S+)#011(?<answer_ttl>\d+)#011(?<answer_class>\w+)#011(?<answer_type>\w+)#011(?<answer_rdata>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJiZwA/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*|ANSWER\sSECTION:)` - `ANSWER SECTION:` substring or the end of the previous match and 0+ whitespaces
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<answer_name>\S+)` - Group "answer_name":  1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `#011` - a literal substring
- `(?<answer_ttl>\d+)` - Group "answer_ttl": 1 or more digits
- `#011` - a literal substring
- `(?<answer_class>\w+)` - Group "answer_class": 1 or more word chars
- `#011` - a literal substring
- `(?<answer_type>\w+)` - Group "answer_type": 1 or more word chars
- `#011` - a literal substring
- `(?<answer_rdata>\S+)` - Group "answer_rdata": 1 or more non-whitespace chars.